# How to Dedupe a Common Context Struct

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-lang

Say for example I have two instructions that have the following account structs:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Ix1Ctx<'info> {
 pub signed: Signer<'info>,
 #[account(
    constraint = token_a_mint.key() == "some mint" @ErrorCode::InvalidMint,
    constraint = token_a_mint.is_initialized
 )]
 pub token_a_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
 #[account(
    constraint = token_b_mint.key() == "some mint a" @ErrorCode::InvalidMint,
    constraint = token_b_mint.is_initialized
 )]
 pub token_b_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
}
```

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Ix2Ctx<'info> {
 pub signed: Signer<'info>,
 #[account(
    constraint = token_a_mint.key() == "some mint b" @ErrorCode::InvalidMint,
    constraint = token_a_mint.is_initialized
 )]
 pub token_a_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
 #[account(
    constraint = token_b_mint.key() == "some mint" @ErrorCode::InvalidMint,
    constraint = token_b_mint.is_initialized
 )]
 pub token_b_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,

 #[account(
    constraint = token_c_mint.key() == "some mint c" @ErrorCode::InvalidMint,
    constraint = token_c_mint.is_initialized
 )]
 pub token_c_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
}
```

Is there a way to de-dupe the `signer, token_a_mint, token_b_mint` from these two structs? They are common among both structs and the checks for them are independent of the checks for the accounts that are not in common.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to the Rust community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the use the composite accounts feature of anchor to factorize the common part.

It would become

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub CommonStuff<'info> {
 pub signed: Signer<'info>,
 #[account(
    constraint = token_a_mint.key() == "some mint" @ErrorCode::InvalidMint,
    constraint = token_a_mint.is_initialized
 )]
 pub token_a_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
 #[account(
    constraint = token_b_mint.key() == "some mint a" @ErrorCode::InvalidMint,
    constraint = token_b_mint.is_initialized
 )]
 pub token_b_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Ix1Ctx<'info> {
    pub common_stuff: CommonStuff<'info>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Ix2Ctx<'info> {
 pub common_stuff: CommonStuff<'info>,
 #[account(
    constraint = token_c_mint.key() == "some mint c" @ErrorCode::InvalidMint,
    constraint = token_c_mint.is_initialized
 )]
 pub token_c_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
}
```

You can check the anchor test as a fully functional example https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/a59aa5f6f39e6ecb6085d9da392132325bdb3577/tests/composite/programs/composite/src/lib.rs